# Calling component function from template

Tags: angular, typescript

In template

```
<tr *ngFor='let activity of pagedWorkflowActivities' [style.background-color]="setBackgroundColor(activity)">
```

In component

```
setBackgroundColor(activity: WorkflowActivity) {
    return 'red';
}
```

I wrote this code in the component in which all other events that are related to same template is written. So I think it is the right place. I just can't get it worked as I am getting this error in developer tool.

> self.parent.context.setBackgroundColor is not a function

Comment: I think you need to add more context. Consider providing a Plunker that allows to reproduce. Plunkers [ New | V ] button provides a ready-to-use Angular2 TS template.

Comment: You're probably not in the same component. As Gûnter said, give more context and add plunkr if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ridiculous, I was trying too many things to make it work but you know what solved it? I just reset IIS (as I am using Asp.Net) and rebuild the solution and it worked. I was getting [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625972/self-context-event-is-not-a-function-while-selecting-value-from-dropdown) few days ago and I gave it up but the next day this issue was gone automatically. Might be caching issue but frustrating one.

**Edit** You can also try `ipconfig /flushdns` command that prevents rebuilding solution unnecessarily.

**Edit** I tried `IE`, `Chrome`, `FF` to test and I found `FF` reflects changes faster than others.